# when i rotate one mesh another seperate mesh deforms

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I have run into a problem. I have a model made from several mesh's, rigged it with one amature, weightpainted very bone more then once, to move the seperate mesh's individual. however when i rotate the left "ear" (seperate mesh) on my owl it moves the glasses (seperate mesh). it also move abit when i move the right "ear", but that i can live with. Im at the point now where in going insane trying to solve it, but dont know what more i can try. Can anyone take a look and maybe help me?
[image]

Comment: You accidentally weight painted the glasses. Select it, toggle to `Weight paint` mode and select the **øre.2.h** `Vertex group`. You'll see it has a light weight assigned to it. To fix that toggle to `Edit mode`, select the entire glasses mesh and remove it from the group. If you want to make sure it doesn't has weight in any other wrong Vertex group you can simply delete all the superfluous groups. Re-check your weights, because other parts of the owl have accidental weights in wrong groups.

Comment: YAY!! Thanks mate. Been pulling my hair out for the problem :)

Comment: How do i thump you up kinda?

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't post an answer, so you can't choose it as one, but you still can upvote comments. Hover my comment with your mouse cursor. You'll see a flag and an arrow up (triangle). The flag is used to report a comment, the arrow is an upvote.

Comment: i dont get the arrow. after a google search i found out i need more reputation to do it.. im so sorry mate. you really helped me alot.